# conda update downgrading TensorFlow from GPU to MKL

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I have created an environment and installed TensorFlow with the command:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow=*=gpu_py310h5ade2b3_0 cudatoolkit cudnn
```

And it installs the latest TensorFlow version available on the `anaconda` channel.
The output of `conda info` below:

```
     active environment : tensorflow
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\miniconda3\current\envs\tensorflow
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Otávio Augusto Silva\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Otávio Augusto Silva\.condarc
          conda version : 22.9.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.13.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.7=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\miniconda3\current  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\miniconda3\current\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\miniconda3\current\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Otávio Augusto Silva\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Otávio Augusto Silva\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\miniconda3\current\envs
                          C:\Users\Otávio Augusto Silva\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Otávio Augusto Silva\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.13 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22000
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

But when I try to update everything by using the command `conda update --all` the following happens:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  tensorflow                      2.9.1-gpu_py310h5ade2b3_0 --> 2.9.1-mkl_py310h0b323c9_0 None
  tensorflow-base                 2.9.1-gpu_py310h9761872_0 --> 2.9.1-mkl_py310h6a7f48e_0 None
```

The question is, how do I prevent `conda update` from downgrading TensorFlow and keep the GPU version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the command `conda update --all tensorflow==2.9.1=gpu_py310*` I can  update the packages normally and maintain the TensorFlow with GPU-enabled build.